# $f\sim N(0, I)$

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, independence

Is it true that

> If $a$ is random vector independent of $x$ for which $P(a'\Sigma a=0)=0$, then $$f\sim N(0,I)$$ and $f$ is independent of $a$ ?

Here $x\sim  N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $f={a'(x-\mu)\over\sqrt{a'\Sigma a}}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the distribution of $f$ is $N(0,1)$ whatever may be the value of $a$. This shows $f$ is distributed independent of $a$.